# Como usar last_insert_id pdo

Tags: php, pdo, insert

hola mi pregunta es como puedo tomar el id (autoincremental) de mi tabla principal a las demas tablas relacionadas ya que me manda 0 en todos mis intentos les dejo el codigo dato :uso modelo mvc.

```
public function getInsert($post){


   $id_velada=mysqli_insert_id();

  /*
    intente declarar la variable  $id_velada y que la mandara con el 
    msqli_insert_id o lastinsertid pero no me manda el id a las tablas
  */

   $fecha=$_POST['fecha'];
   $responsable_velada=$_POST['responsable_velada'];
   $autorizo=$_POST['autorizo']; 
   $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
   $apellidop=$_POST['apellidop']; 
   $apellidom=$_POST['apellidom'];
   $area=$_POST['area'];  
   $clave=$_POST['clave']; 
   $descripcion=$_POST['descripcion'];
   $tipo_gasto=$_POST['tipo_gasto'];
```

quiero mandar y poner el id generado autoincremetalmente de la tabla velada a las demás tablas ya que se relacionan con el id_velada no es llave foranea es solo relación mediante programación

```
 $sql1 = "INSERT INTO velada (fecha, responsable_velada, autorizo)
          VALUES ('$fecha', '$responsable_velada', '$autorizo')";

 $sql2 = "INSERT INTO personal_velada (id_velada, fecha, nombre, apellidop, apellidom, area)
                VALUES ($id_velada, '$fecha', '$nombre', '$apellidop', '$apellidom', '$area')";

  $sql3 = "INSERT INTO ordenes_trabajo (id_velada, clave, descripcion)
                VALUES ($id_velada, '$clave', '$descripcion')";

 $sql4 = "INSERT INTO gastos_velada (id_velada, fecha , tipo_gasto)
        VALUES ($id_velada, '$fecha', '$tipo_gasto')";


$query1 = $this->db->prepare($sql1);
$query1->execute();

 $query2 = $this->db->prepare($sql2);
 $query2->execute();

 $query3 = $this->db->prepare($sql3);

  $query3->execute();

 $query4 = $this->db->prepare($sql4); 

 $query4->execute();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola amigos ya lo resolvi con ayuda de mi asesor estaba bien el codigo pero mal acomodado :v les dejo la respuesta:

```
  public function getInsert($post){


   $fecha=$_POST['fecha'];
   $responsable_velada=$_POST['responsable_velada'];
   $autorizo=$_POST['autorizo']; 
   $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
   $apellidop=$_POST['apellidop']; 
   $apellidom=$_POST['apellidom'];
   $area=$_POST['area'];  
   $clave=$_POST['clave']; 
   $descripcion=$_POST['descripcion'];
   $tipo_gasto=$_POST['tipo_gasto'];


   $sql1 = "INSERT INTO velada (fecha, responsable_velada, autorizo)
      VALUES ('$fecha', '$responsable_velada', '$autorizo')";
   $query1 = $this->db->prepare($sql1);
   $query1->execute();
   $id_velada=$this->db->lastInsertId();

   $sql2 = "INSERT INTO personal_velada (id_velada, fecha, nombre, apellidop, apellidom, area)
            VALUES ($id_velada, '$fecha', '$nombre', '$apellidop', '$apellidom', '$area')";
   $query2 = $this->db->prepare($sql2);
   $query2->execute();
   $sql3 = "INSERT INTO ordenes_trabajo (id_velada, clave, descripcion)
            VALUES ($id_velada, '$clave', '$descripcion')";
    $query3 = $this->db->prepare($sql3);
    $query3->execute();

    $sql4 = "INSERT INTO gastos_velada (id_velada, fecha , tipo_gasto)
    VALUES ($id_velada,'$fecha', '$tipo_gasto')";
    $query4 = $this->db->prepare($sql4); 
    $query4->execute();
    echo $id_velada;

}
```